# SQL Server Issue with select causing proc to hang

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that uses OUTPUT variables to return data, a single record. I can execute it and it return the data just fine.

```
Exec CalculateDomesticPrice @SKU, @CustomerGroupID, @Qty, 
     @BasePrice OUTPUT, @CurrentTierPrice OUTPUT, @Tier1Price OUTPUT, 
     @Tier2Price OUTPUT, @Tier3Price OUTPUT, @SetupPrice OUTPUT
```

However I need it to insert data into a temp table and then I just do a select.

But it just hangs and never complete. Am I doing something really stupid ?

Here is the snippet of a test proc I wrote to debug the issue.

```
create proc GetDomesticPrice (
@SKU varchar(50), 
@CustomerGroupID INT, 
@Qty INT
AS
BEGIN
Declare @BasePrice money = 0
Declare @CurrentTierPrice money = 0
Declare @Tier1Price money = 0
Declare @Tier2Price money = 0
Declare @Tier3Price money = 0
Declare @SetupPrice money = 0
declare @TempPrices table
(
BlankCapPrice money,
CurrentTierPrice  money,
Tier1Price money,
Tier2Price money,
Tier3Price money,
SetupPrice money
)
Exec CalculateDomesticPrice @SKU, @CustomerGroupID, @Qty, @BasePrice OUTPUT,         @CurrentTierPrice OUTPUT, @Tier1Price OUTPUT, @Tier2Price OUTPUT, @Tier3Price OUTPUT, @SetupPrice OUTPUT
Insert into @TempPrices values (@BasePrice, @CurrentTierPrice, @Tier1Price, @Tier2Price, @Tier3Price, @SetupPrice)
select @BasePrice, @CurrentTierPrice, @Tier1Price, @Tier2Price, @Tier3Price, @SetupPrice
END
```

Comment: Does the proc hang when executed from SSMS, or only when run via the app code?

Comment: Use the technique described here: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1660/using-the-nowait-option-with-the-sql-server-raiserror-statement/ to add statements to your test proc to output something after each line. That will tell you what line it it hangs on. When you run `CalculateDomesticPrice ` and the insert alone, does they return? Perhaps `CalculateDomesticPrice ` is just really slow?

Comment: Verify that the stored procedure doesn't simply fail with the error going somewhere you can't see. Also try `EXEC ... WITH RECOMPILE` to verify it's not just a bad cached execution plan for a particular value of `@SKU`.

Comment: So I used the RaiseException in the called Proc and calling proc but nothing gets printed after 3 min. The called proc takes about 34 sec to finish when I execute it on the command line. I moved the insert into Temp table into the Called Proc instead and it still hangs. It's so bizarre. Tried the EXEC..WITH RECOMPILE. Same result.

Comment: Forgot to add. I am using a linked server that reads from MySQL